# Selenium chrome mobile emulation with touch feature

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mobileemulation

mobile emulation with device metrics as instructions:

```
"deviceMetrics" => { "width" => 360, "height" => 640, "pixelRatio" => 3.0, touch: true }
```

[touch feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exmz7.png)

The code runs well except the touch feature, the screen can't be touched, slipped, and cant't trigger any touch event.

It seems that touch screen feature has been deprecated. How to active the touch feature?

Similar to the question:

[Selenium - mobile emulation (chrome dev tools) not showing touch circle](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/selenium-mobile-emulation-chrome-dev-tools-not-showing-touch-circle/536968)

I run the code with Ruby and Python.

Python env:

`Python 3.7.7`
`selenium 4.11.2`
`selenium-wire 5.1.0`

`Chrome 116.0.5845.187`
`ChromeDriver 116.0.5845.96`

code:

```
mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0, "touch": True, "mobile": True },
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SM-G977U Build/RP1A.200720.012; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Mobile Safari/537.36",
    "clientHints": {"platform": "Android", "mobile": True} }

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chrome_options)
```

Comment: This is purely a selenium issue and should not be tagged with "python" or "ruby".

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix it, although I'd rather know the solution in "python" or "ruby". You know,  the ruby support is poor.

Comment: I might be fighting an uphill battle, but when you tag with “ruby” then ruby developers who don’t even know Selenium are going to get your question in their feed.  You’re not having a ruby issue, you’re having a Selenium issue.  It’s the wrong audience.